# Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, sqlite

I get this warning message in my php:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

How should I fix that? Where can I get this sqlite.so file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to get it. Just remove the line referencing the shared object.

```
cd /etc/php5
grep -rinH sqlite .
```

Since PHP 5.4 [sqlite is only available via PECL](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php).

If you want to get the library, try `sudo apt-get install php-sqlite` or `yum install php-sqlite` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas: (Re-) install php-sqlite on your machine or remove the line which loads the sqlite.so. Mostly done by an extra config in /etc/php5/conf.d/

If you don't have shell access, call you system administrator and give him that error message.

Answer (score 0):

The .so file was removed in Ubuntu 11.10 ([bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/875262)), however you can still install it manually...

- Download the old package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty-updates/php5-sqlite
- Extracts sqlite.so to the required directory
- Change it's ownership to root:root

Answer (score 0):

1. you must have sure  sqlite installed
2. goto  /etc/php.d  and find sqlite.ini

   1. you must somethong like :  extension=mysql.so
   2. mysql.so must be in : /usr/lib64/php/modules/
           if not you must  install it

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/redis.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/redis.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/redis.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/redis.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I was getting this error/warning resolved it by uninstalling and installing redis

```
brew uninstall php54-redis
brew install php54-redis
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning when I wanted to install the symfony/security-bundle bundle in my Symfony 4 project:

`composer require symfony/security-bundle`

Here the warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked my **/etc/php/php.ini** file and I uncommented the line **extension=pdo_sqlite** line. I had to install the package php-sqlite via my package manager because the file pdo_sqlite.so must be present in the **/usr/lib/php/modules/** folder:

`pacman -S php-sqlite`

After, I typed again the composer command and the warning disappeared. I hope my answer can help you.